# SQLAlchemy ORDER BY DESCENDING?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I use ORDER BY `descending` in a SQLAlchemy query like the following?

This query works, but returns them in ascending order:

```py
query = (model.Session.query(model.Entry)
        .join(model.ClassificationItem)
        .join(model.EnumerationValue)
        .filter_by(id=c.row.id)
        .order_by(model.Entry.amount) # This row :)
        )
```

If I try:

```
.order_by(desc(model.Entry.amount))
```

then I get: `NameError: global name 'desc' is not defined`.

Comment: Import desc from sqlalchemy 

`from sqlalchemy import desc`

Comment: What do you mean using `model.Entry.amount`? U can just use `.order_by(Model.field)`

Comment: @fedotsoldier It’s the same thing, OP is just using `import model` + `model.Class.field` instead of `from model import Class` + `Class.field`.

Answer (score 451, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy import desc
someselect.order_by(desc(table1.mycol))
```

[Usage](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc) from @jpmc26

Comment: Docs have a [new url](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc)

Answer (score 1048):

Just as an FYI, you can also specify those things as column attributes. For instance, I might have done:

```
.order_by(model.Entry.amount.desc())
```

This is handy since it avoids an `import`, and you can use it on other places such as in a relation definition, etc.

For more information, you can refer this [SQLAlchemy 1.4 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc)

Comment: Is there an API reference for this, would be cool to know what else is available?

Comment: Thanks for the this. It seems it is missing from official documentation.

Comment: The best response (at the moment).

Comment: @JohnMike http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.desc

Comment: The sqlalchemy orm doc is a mystery for me, i can never find anything by myself in it. Thank you @dzervas

Answer (score 99):

One other thing you might do is:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
...
.order_by(text("name desc")
```

This will result in: ORDER BY name desc. The disadvantage here is the explicit column name used in order by.

Comment: This is a potentially brittle workaround where a workaround is not needed.

Comment: This is nice if you have the sort column in a string for any reason, though (like sanitized input in a web API).

Comment: As a followup, you can also do `getattr(MyModelClass, column_string).desc()` if you've got a string.

Comment: @JimStewart and for passing in direction I ended up using: `qry.order_by(getattr(getattr(Song, sort_by), sort_dir)())`

Comment: You can also use this if you have labeled your output and are sorting by a computed column instead of a model column

Comment: @boatcoder .. 3 yrs later... do you have an example handy of how to do that ascending?

Comment: Answering my comment.. ```from sqlalchemy import asc, desc```, then ```.order_by(asc("label"))```

Answer (score 58):

You can use `.desc()` function in your query just like this:

```
query = (model.Session.query(model.Entry)
        .join(model.ClassificationItem)
        .join(model.EnumerationValue)
        .filter_by(id=c.row.id)
        .order_by(model.Entry.amount.desc())
        )
```

This will order by amount in descending order
or

```
query = session.query(
    model.Entry
).join(
    model.ClassificationItem
).join(
    model.EnumerationValue
).filter_by(
    id=c.row.id
).order_by(
    model.Entry.amount.desc()
)
)
```

Use of desc function of SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import desc
query = session.query(
    model.Entry
).join(
    model.ClassificationItem
).join(
    model.EnumerationValue
).filter_by(
    id=c.row.id
).order_by(
    desc(model.Entry.amount)
)
)
```

For official docs please use the [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc) or check below snippet:

> sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc(column) Produce a descending ORDER BY
> clause element.
>
> e.g.:
>
> ```
> from sqlalchemy import desc
>
> stmt = select([users_table]).order_by(desc(users_table.c.name))
> ```
>
> will produce SQL as:
>
> ```
> SELECT id, name FROM user ORDER BY name DESC
> ```
>
> The desc() function is a standalone version of the
> ColumnElement.desc() method available on all SQL expressions, e.g.:
>
> ```
> stmt = select([users_table]).order_by(users_table.c.name.desc())
> ```
>
> Parameters column – A ColumnElement (e.g. scalar SQL expression) with
> which to apply the desc() operation.
>
> See also
>
> asc()
>
> nullsfirst()
>
> nullslast()
>
> Select.order_by()

Comment: how is this not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/4187279/2718295

Answer (score 18):

You can try: `.order_by(ClientTotal.id.desc())`

```
session = Session()
auth_client_name = 'client3' 
result_by_auth_client = session.query(ClientTotal).filter(ClientTotal.client ==
auth_client_name).order_by(ClientTotal.id.desc()).all()

for rbac in result_by_auth_client:
    print(rbac.id) 
session.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Complementary at @Radu answer, As in SQL, you can add the table name in the parameter if you have many table with the same attribute.

```
.order_by("TableName.name desc")
```

Comment: Doesn’t this require wrapping the string by text()?

Comment: Take in care it cause an error in SQLAlchemy >1.3, a warning in lower versions