# The default sorting criteria of sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Now I sort the data in the database by its attribute 1. 
If there is a tie of different items with same value of attribute 1, the data seems to be sorted by its id. 
However, I would like to break the tie by sorting by desc(id). How could I change the default sorting criteria of the database if there is a tie?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

**Update**

Since version 1.1 the `order_by` parameter in the mapper configuration [has been deprecated](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_11.html#change-09669497f855398505a14d647f0b239c). Instead [Query.order_by](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/current/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.order_by) must be used.

```py
db.query(User).order_by(User.fullname)

# or in desc order
db.query(User).order_by(User.fullname.desc())
```

**I left here the original answer for historial purposes**:

This is possible by means of the [mapper configuration](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.params.order_by).

If you have a user table and want to retrieve the records always ordered by `fullname` something like this should works:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "order_by": fullname,
    }
    
    def __repr__(self):
       return f"<User(id='{self.id}', name='{self.name}', fullname='{self.fullname}')>"
```

Default `order_by` is ascending, if you want to reverse the order this can be used:

```py
__mapper_args__ = {
    "order_by": fullname.desc(),
}
```

Comment: Adding a default ordering in mapper configuration has been deprecated since version 1.1 in favour of explicitly using `Query.order_by()`.

Comment: `desc` in case you needed it `__mapper_args__ = { "order_by":  id.desc() }`

Comment: The feature works well on version `SQLAlchemy==1.3.17` but fails on `1.4.35`
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'order_by'`

Answer (score 8):

The order is entirely determined by the database, not SQLAlchemy. With plain SQL you just add additional ORDER BY clauses, in SQLAlchemy ORM you do the same by chaining order_by methods. For example:

```
for eq in session.query(Equipment).order_by(Equipment.model_id).order_by(Equipment.name).all():
    print (eq)
```

Whichever is left-most is the primary sort.

Comment: BTW, how to sort *DESC* with SQLAlchemy is answered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4186062/851737).