# Default order_by clause in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I set a default order_by clause in a class definition in SQLAlchemy, so that any query against this class will automatically have this clause?

The ORM docs for order_by talk about mapper.order_by but says that this is deprecated, and also mentions overriding existing order_by settings but without saying how these settings might get there.

Comment: The documentation tells you to use `Query.order_by()` instead - which means there is no practical way to avoid ordering on query level. This makes a lot of sense anyway, as ordering happens on database and consumes resources. A default clause would cause your database to sort even those results you do not need to have sorted.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361264/the-default-sorting-criteria-of-sqlalchemy.