# building a sorting function for SQLAlchemy and jquery datatables

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, datatables

I would like to use jQuery DataTables with my SQLAlchemy models. Datatables can be configured to use server-side processing for things like sorting, filtering, searching, etc.

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658974/cleaning-up-my-sqlalchemy-operations-reducing-repetition) concerning reducing repetition in my code for the filtering since I have many models with various column names that will be filtered on.

The code that GG_Python provided works well so far.

Now I am having issues with filtering on model relationships. For example, I have a User model like below

```
class User(Model):
    ...
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    region_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('regions.id'), nullable=False)
    firstname = Column(String(20))
    ...
```

and a Region model like below

```
class Region(Model):
    ...
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('region_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    users = relationship('User', backref='region', order_by='User.id', lazy='joined')
```

I am struggling wrapping my head around how to query this in a way that will fit in a function. I am afraid I am looking at it in a far too complicated manner.

What am I missing to be able to search on the relationships that have been set up, ideally building off of [GG_Python's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29679373/2224777)?

The `type(mapper[col_name])` is either `sqlalchemy.orm.properties.ColumnProperty` or `sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty`

```
q = User.query
rv = rv = request.values
q = filter_model_by_request(q, User, rv):

...

def filter_model_by_request(qry, model, rv):
    mapper = inspect(model).attrs
    col_names = list(set([c.key for c in mapper]) & set(rv.keys()))
    for col_name in col_names:
        if type(mapper[col_name]) == ColumnProperty:
            col = mapper[col_name].columns[0]
            col_type = type(col.type)
            if col_type == String:  # filter for String
                qry = qry.filter(col.ilike('%{0}%'.format(rv.get(col_name))))
            elif: ... # filter other types

        elif type(mapper[col_name]) == RelationshipProperty:
            # what the heck goes here?
```

How can I perform a query for `users where user.region.name = SearchString`,? Hopefully in a function that keeps it DRY

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [sqlalchemy-datatables](http://sqlalchemy-datatables.rtfd.org)? I think it does exactly what you need.

> sqlalchemy-datatables is a library providing an SQLAlchemy integration of jQuery DataTables. It helps you manage server side requests in your application.
>
> It is framework agnostic, tested with Pyramid and Flask mainly.