# Custom collections in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sorting, sqlalchemy

I use Declarative flavor of SQL Alchemy with a PostgreSQL database. I have a `ClaimAccount` that manages `Claim` objects. Something like:

```
class Claim(MyBase):
    manager_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey(ClaimAccount.id))
    manager = relationship(ClaimAccount, backref='claims')
    created = Column(DATE)
```

Now, if `a` is a `ClaimAccount`, then `a.claims` is a list of `Claim`s. That's fine, but I'd like it to be sorted by `created` column, since I *always* want to iterate through `.claims` in order from oldest to newest. Of course I can sort it in Python, but probably it would be better (clearer, faster, DRYer, more convenient) if Postgres did that for me.

At first I thought that the answer was to set `collection_class` on a relationship to some PriorityQueue or SortedList or whatever, but now I think it would only affect how the claims are stuffed into Python data structures, not how they are fetched from the database. Also, the documentation says that "in most cases you don't need a custom collection implementation" (however, the cases mentioned there do not include mine, it seems).

Do you have any advice on how best to do this?

Comment: You can order queryset by any field. See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186062/sqlalchemy-order-by-descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `order_by` argument to the relationship. Because the order applies to backref, you can do it like this:

```
manager = relationship(ClaimAccount, backref=backref('claims', order_by=Claims.created.desc()))
```

See also the [Ordering List extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/orderinglist.html).