# Is there a way to sort by descending created time using a Python lambda?

Tags: python, database, sorting, lambda, sqlalchemy

I'm working with SqlAlchemy to query a database containing a list of events. Each event has a created time and an ari (amazon resource number).  There's a maximum number of records I can get back from one function call, and I want to get back the records starting with the most recent first. To do this I need to manually pass in a lambda function that sorts the records properly; documentation for the argument is here:

```
cols (default=None):
    A function which takes a DBObject class and returns a tuple of columns (or SQLAlchemy
    expressions) used to compare it. This overrides the default sorting behaviour.
    Example: key=lambda x: (x.created, x.ari)
```

As you can see, by default it sorts by x.created, then x.ari, both in ascending order. I actually need to do the opposite of this and sort by x.created, then x.ari, in *descending* order. Is there any way I can do this with just a lambda? Using sort() or sorted() is not really an option due to me using this pre-existing function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLAlchemy ORDER BY DESCENDING?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186062/sqlalchemy-order-by-descending)

Comment: Per the dupe, the SQLAlchemy expressions you seek are `desc(x.created)` and `desc(x.ari)`. See [Column Element Modifier Constructors](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#column-element-modifier-constructors) from the SQLAlchemy docs. The total key function for this scenario would be `lambda x: (desc(x.created), desc(x.ari))`.

Comment: @DanielHao Using `sort/sorted` isn't possible since that would require fetching the entire database. Also, AFAIK `-x.created` isn't a valid SQLAlchemy expression

Comment: @Brian Trying that I run into an error that says ```ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected, got object of type <class 'freezegun.api.FakeDatetime'> instead``` - Can I only sort by strings or something?  The example in the SqlAlchemy code uses it like so ``` stmt = select([users_table]).order_by(desc(users_table.c.name))``` - Do I need to access some attribute of the created column or something?